# GSS4 - Segment Tree implementation 2

Tags: c++, performance, programming-challenge, tree, time-limit-exceeded

The problem is also known as GSS4. The exact detail can be seen [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/GSS4/) but I reached TLE.

> You are given a sequence A of N(N <= 100,000) positive integers. There
>   sum will be less than \$10^{18}\$. On this sequence you have to apply M (M <=
>   100,000) operations:
>
> (A) For given x,y, for each elements between the x-th and the y-th
>   ones (inclusively, counting from 1), modify it to its positive square
>   root (rounded down to the nearest integer).
>
> (B) For given x,y, query the sum of all the elements between the x-th
>   and the y-th ones (inclusively, counting from 1) in the sequence.
>   Input
>
> Multiple test cases, please proceed them one by one. Input terminates
>   by EOF.
>
> For each test case:
>
> The first line contains an integer N. The following line contains N
>   integers, representing the sequence A1..AN. The third line contains an
>   integer M. The next M lines contain the operations in the form "i x
>   y".i=0 denotes the modify operation, i=1 denotes the query operation.

It's a classic segment tree--my very first one to be exact.

I asked my friend if I need Lazy Propagation but he said no. The only optimization that I did is if tree[X]=1, I don't update it anymore since sqrt(1) = 1

Is there a wrong implementation in my ST that causes TLE?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

static unsigned long long int list[100000];
static unsigned long long int tree[264000];
int N, bigLevel;

void reset(){
    int K;
    for(K=0;K<100000;K++){
        list[K]=0;
    }
    for(K=0;K<264000;K++){
        tree[K]=0;
    }
}

void update(int from, int to){
    int start = ((int) pow(2,bigLevel-1)-1);
    int X, K;
    unsigned long long int J, diff;
    for(X=from-1;X<to;X++){
        //checking the root
        J= sqrt(tree[start+X]);
        diff = tree[start+X]-J;
        tree[start+X] = J;
        K = start+X;
        //if tree[start+X] is not 1, then we have some updates to do
        if(diff>0){
            //I understand that in ST, it's usually one indexed
            //but since it's my first time I create ST, I want to 
            //make it zero indexed
            while(K>0){
                K = (K-1)/2;
                tree[K] -= diff;
            }
        }
    }
}

void buildTree(){
    int level = 0;
    int X = N, J, c = 0;
    while(X>0){
        X /= 2;
        if(X%2 && X>1){
            c+=1;
        }
        level += 1;
    }
    if(c>0){
        level += 1;
    }
    bigLevel = level;
    // Building root
    int start = ((int) pow(2,level-1))-1;
    J = 0;
    for(X=start;X<((int) pow(2,level))-1;X++){
        tree[X] =  list[J];
        J += 1;
    }
    while(level>1){
        level-=1;
        start = ((int) pow(2,level-1))-1;
        J = 0;
        for(X=start; X<((int) pow(2,level))-1;X++){
            tree[X] = tree[(int) pow(2,level)-1 + (2*J)] + tree[(int) pow(2,level) + (2*J)];
            J += 1;
        }
    }
}

unsigned long long int query(int from, int to){
    unsigned long long int total = 0;
    int start = (int) pow(2,bigLevel-1)-1;
    int X, Y, Z, pos,gow;
    X = from-1;
    while(X<to){
        //printf("%llu %d\n",total,X);
        int pos = start + X;
        int cupid = X;
        int size = 1;
        int chunk = (int) pow(2,bigLevel-1);
        Z = X;
        gow = start;
        while(1){
            size *= 2;
            chunk /= 2;
            Y = Z / 2;
            // range = size(Z) <= from-1 < to-1 < size(Z+1)
            //Checking if not in range
            //If it's not in range, we climb one level too much
            if (!(X <= (size*Y)) || !((size*(Y+1)) < to-1)){
                total += tree[gow + Z];
                X = cupid+1; //isi
                break;
            }
            Z /= 2;
            gow /= 2;
            cupid = size*(Y+1)-1;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

int main(){
    int T=1;
    while(scanf("%d",&N)==1){
        printf("Case #%d:\n",T);
        int I, K;
        reset();
        for(I=0;I<N;I++){
            scanf("%d",&list[I]);
        }
        buildTree();
        scanf("%d",&K);
        int A,B,C;
        for(I=0;I<K;I++){
            scanf("%d %d %d",&A,&B,&C);
            if(A==0){
                update(B,C);
            }
            else{
                printf("%llu\n",query(B,C));
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        T+=1;
    }
}
```

Edit:

- It still TLE despite using cin cout that is not synchronized with Scanf.
- People (who got AC) keep insisting that the problem is not in the square root, since it takes only 7 iterations.

Comment: This is supposed to be C++, right? So why did you bother with implementing a custom data structure? `std::vector` would have offered all you need. Anyway - the lesson of that challenge wasn't data handling, but efficiently calculating the squareroot of an integer. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28976649/2879325 for a solution to the actual problem.

Comment: I am anticipating if I have to downgrade to C. Programming class can be cruel.

Comment: And the sqrt solution is compiler specific...

Comment: My friend hinted that I should use while(cin) instead of while(scanf)

Comment: your friend was correct.